# Apache SSL multi domain

Tags: apache, ssl

We have a web application that hosts multiple websites for our customers under different domains. All these domains are hosted on an single apache vhost, the logical seperation into different sites is done by the software.

We would like to offer ssl-support for some of these virtual websites. Pricipically that should be no problem, as after an ssl connection is established, the software can use the host: header to route to the correct website.

But: How do I tell apache to serve the correct certificate, depending on the requested host?

Is there a possibity to map certs to domains, e.g. with something like:

SSLCertificateFile file

All help is appreciated!

Comment: If they all running on the same vhost, then they should all use the same certificate - unless you mean something else by "same vhost" e.g. a wildcard vhost file? Certainly if you need more than one certificate, tou'll need more than one IP address - hence the solution should be evidence

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what @bobince said, you can have multiple host names in the same certificate (not necessarily with wild-cards or sub-domains) using multiple DNS entries in the subject alternative name extension. (CAs are likely to charge a much higher fee for this type of certificate).

Comment: This is the easiest method, and most SAN certificates are only slightly more expensive: http://www.sslshopper.com/unified-communications-uc-ssl-certificates.html

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Since the host header is only sent after the SSL connection is set up, the server can not serve a SSL certificate depending on the host.

[Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) tries to fix this, but is not implemented on all browsers.

Comment: Specifically, Server Name Indication does not work for Internet Explorer under Windows XP.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use a separate IP address per SSL domain. You can set the `SSLCertificateFile` okay on a VirtualHost that has an IP:port combination to itself.

It is a limitation of HTTPS that you choosing a certificate to secure the connection happens *before* the client passes a `Host:` request header (it has to, because the headers are also encrypted). So you can't have more than one hostname per IP address (except for wildcard certs, and that only gives you subdomains).

An extension to SSL known as [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) works around this problem, but browser support is not currently good enough to consider for public deployment.

Comment: +1 You also have the option of "unrelated" host names in multiple entries in the SAN extension.

Comment: This may be a possible way: To use an combination of ip:port to serve multiple vhosts, each of them pointing to the same DocumentRoot. All we need to do in addition, is to open the firewall for these ports in order to let requests in and keep track what port belogs to what instance. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @D.Bel ca The problem with multiple ip:port, is that https uses 443 by default and not all of the possible client's firewalls will let connections to other ports (it varies, but it's not just about your firewall, but also about theirs). It is quite common for HTTP proxy servers will only allow `CONNECT` (which is used for proxying https) to port 443.